# Why does getppid return the same value, even for grandchild processes?

Tags: c, linux, fork, parent

This is my code and to execute this program I run `./2c 10 5` —
10 for argument1 and 5 for argument2. The program will run 10 child processes, and the 5th child is going to make another child, but in this case my ppid is always the same. It never changes. So for every child, I got the same ppid,

The output I get is:

```
pid: 1 ppid: 6
pid: 2 ppid: 6
pid: 3 ppid: 6
pid: 4 ppid: 6
pid: 5 ppid: 6``
pid: 6 ppid: 6
pid: 7 ppid: 6
pid: 8 ppid: 6
pid: 9 ppid: 6
pid: 10 ppid: 6
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[],char *envp[])
{
  int i,a;

  a=getpid();
  int pid;
  int child,child2;
  child=atoi(argv[1]);
  child2=atoi(argv[2]);

  if(atoi(argv[2])>atoi(argv[1]))
  {
    printf("arg2 is bigger than arg1!");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(i=1;i<=child;i++)
  {
    pid=fork();
    if(i=child2 && pid==0)
    {
      pid=fork();
      break;
    }
    if(pid==0)
      break;
  }

  if(getpid()!=a)
    if(getppid()==a)
    {
      printf("PID: %d   PPID: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

      sleep(5);
      exit(0);
    }

  for(i=1;i<=child+1;i++)
    wait(0);

  return 0; 
}
```

---

this is my code can someone test this and send the output on this site...so i can compare..to compile i use gcc test.c -o test and to run ./test 10 5...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
int i,a;
a=getpid();
pid_t pid;
int child,child2;
child=atoi(argv[1]);
child2=atoi(argv[2]);

if(atoi(argv[2])>atoi(argv[1]))
{
    printf("2nd argumentet is bigger than 1st");
    exit(1);
}
for(i=1;i<=child;i++)
{
    pid=fork();
    if(i==child2 && pid==0)
    {
        pid=fork();
        break;
    }
if(pid==0)
    break;
}
if(getpid()!=child2)
{
    printf("PID: %d  PPID: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    sleep(5);   
    exit(0);
}
for(i=0;i<=child+1;i++)
wait(0);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You might consider using `-Wall` to compile your code, this *at least* points you to bugs like the one mentioned by wildplasser above.

Comment: im not so good at linux..so what do you mean with -Wall

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't demonstrate what you claim is happening. You *only* print output from the children, never the grandchild, because you specifically check for the children with this line:

```
if(getppid()==a)
```

In that line, `a` holds the pid of the original instance of your program. That won't change because when you call `fork`, you've already passed the line that assigned `a`. The parent pid of all the immediate children is always the same because that's what *parent* means.

Remove the line I've highlighted above, and you should see the results you were expecting.

Comment: ok i´m getting different ppid what i can see but i get a loop that wont stopp...is there any easier code for this

Comment: Your loop never terminates because of the problem Wildplasser obliquely pointed out in his or her comment. In your code, you're *assigning* a new value to `i` in that conditional statement. You meant to *compare* the value of `i` with `child2`. You need to use the `==` operator instead of the `=` operator. If you had used the `-Wall` option when you ran your compiler, the compiler would have warned you about your mistaken operator usage.

Comment: ok now the loop is gone..but still it doesnt work, the output i´m getting is pid 2 ppid 3                                               pid 4 ppid 3 and so on  and my 5 child process dont have another child it´s my 8th child whos getting it

Comment: Maybe the OS isn't scheduling the children to run in the order you expect. Sounds like you have some more debugging to do. Stack Overflow is not meant as a personal debugging substitute, and I think I have sufficiently answered the question you asked here initially, so it's time for you to go work on your problem on your own for a while. When you've debugged as much as you can, please come back and post a new question.

Comment: thanks for the help...like a said im not good at linux, and i know the code is right...because its working on my friends computer but not mine...so im just stuck...i dont know what to do next